# How To Execute a BELOW MENTION CTE From VB,NET CODE?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, command, common-table-expression

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
       SELECT [Status] , 
              [Date] , 
              [Time] , 
              Cast([Date] AS DATETIME) + Cast([Time] AS DATETIME) AS [datetime] 
       FROM   @MyTable ) 
SELECT   [Status] , 
         [Date] , 
         [Time] , 
         Cast(Dateadd(minute, Datediff(minute, Lag([datetime]) OVER ( ORDER BY [datetime] ), [datetime]), '00:00:00') AS TIME) AS timedifference
WHERE    date BETWEEN '"& DATETIMEPICKER1.VALUE.DATE &"' AND      '"& DATETIMEPICKER2.VALUE.DATE &"'
from     cte
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please uopdate on answer

Comment: You arent asking a question, You ask for a tutorial and we dont do that here. Your question is [**off topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you ask how execute `select * from Mytable from VB.NET`  would get the same answer.